# How to parse external JSON file using Web Workers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i read a JSON file using WEB WORKERS in javascript? 
I pass the name of the JSON file I want to read (data.json) from main.html to WORKER.js file.
Now Worker.js should parse the JSON I passed it and return the result to main.html. However, JSON.parse(data.json) is not working in Worker.json.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` only knows how to handle strings with data. If you have an external resource, you first need to fetch it using [`XHR`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to fetch `.json` from server. And simply use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

     //data is returned as parsed object, no need to parse it!
     console.log(data);
});
```

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sh8ZL/1/).